Locally compact group whose unitary irreducible reps are one dimensional
It's known that if G is a finite group such that all its irreducible unitary representations are one-dimensional, then G is abelian. This uses the fact that the left regular representation decomposes as the direct sum over the irreducible unitary representations of G.
If G is now instead a locally compact topological group such that the left regular representation on $L^2(G)$ decomposes as a direct integral over the irreducible unitary (strongly continuous) representations of G, does the result still hold?

I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you requiring that those representations are 1-dimensional? Otherwise, take G=SO(3) (compact and non-abelian), then L^2(G) certainly decomposes the way you require.

Yes, I'm requiring the unitary irreducible representations to be one-dimensional, and the question is whether that forces the group to be abelian, atleast in the case where the left regular representation decomposes as a direct integral over the irreducible unitary representations.

This is always true, no assumptions concerning direct integral decomposition are needed.
More precisely: if $G$ is a locally compact, Hausdorff topological group and all irreducible representations of $G$ are one dimensional, then $G$ is abelian.
Proof: Assume that $G$ is not abelian. Then there are $x,y\in G$ such that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\neq e$. By Gelfand-Raikov theorem (see e.g. Corollary C.5.9 "Kazhdan property (T)" - Bekka, de la Harpe, Vallete) there is an irreducible representation $\pi$ such that $\pi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})\neq \mathbb{1}$. By assumption, $\pi$ is one dimensional (is a character), hence $\pi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=\pi(x)\pi(y)\pi(x)^{-1}\pi(y)^{-1}=1$, contradiction.
